# How to update the time in html for the elapsed time using PHP and jquety

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datetime

How can I update the time elapsed without refreshing the page using jquery,

It checks if the time session isset to be displayed time elapsed in seconds

```
<?php
if (!isset($_SESSION['start_time'][$pId])) {
    $_SESSION['start_time'][$presentId] = time();
}
$end_time = time();

$timeDiff = $end_time - $_SESSION['start_time'][$pId];
?>
```

**form**

```
<form>
    <input type="hidden" name="time_taken" id="quesId_<?php echo $v->id ?>"
           value="<?php echo $timeDiff ?>">
</form>
```

This displays the time elapsed in the seconds on each page refresh;

```
<div class="well timer"><i class=" icon-time"></i> <span
        class="response-time"><?php echo $timeDiff ?> </span>
</div>
```

**script**

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {

        //setTimeout(timeUpdate(), 1000);
        function timeUpdate() {
            var time = $("#quesId_<?php echo $pId ?>").val();
            //alert(time);
            console.log(time);
            $('.response-time').text(time);
            setTimeout(timeUpdate(), 1000);
        }

        timeUpdate();


    });
</script>
```

Comment: php runs on server and javascript runs in browser. This could all be done with  javascript using Date api. You can also use ajax to make server side requests

Comment: the php session is just to see if user refreshes the page so its time does not reset, once it loads the times can start counter form that time ... but when  do settimeout the page hangs

Comment: calling `setTimout` wrong change to `setTimeout(timeUpdate, 1000);`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @charlietfl

Error was declaring the variable inside the function that has to be outside the function and the timer has to be incremented in every call;

```
 var time = $("#quesId_<?php echo $pId ?>").val();
            function timeUpdate() {
                //alert(time);
                console.log(time);
                time++;
                $('.response-time').text(time);
                setTimeout(timeUpdate, 1000);
            }

            timeUpdate();
```